Fitting a Nonlinear Mixed Model
I’m trying to fit a nonLinear Mixed Model (nLMM) to test whether the abundance of certain organisms was affected by the sampling period after an event that caused a significant increase.
The data show an important curve where the abundance of these organisms surged after the event (event between sampling_period: -1 and 1) but then declined.
I’m trying to construct a nonLinear Mixed Model, but I’ve found it quite challenging to understand how to build the model (e.g., model <- lmer(abundance ~ sampling_period + (1 | rep), data = data). I’d really appreciate any help in determining whether the abundance was affected by the sampling period.
data <- data.frame(
  abundance = c(79, 72, 58, 61, 88, 123, 119, 96, 67, 78, 143, 75, 105, 46, 58, 
                127, 173, 181, 67, 120, 64, 30, 49, 47, 104, 83, 146, 118, 53, 
                98, 223, 257, 255, 292, 354, 133, 129, 140, 27, 55, 68, 148, 
                122, 132, 77, 121, 108, 109),
  rep = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", 
          "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", 
          "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", 
          "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T2", "T3"),
  sampling_period_consecutive = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
                                  6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 
                                  10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 
                                  14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16),
  sampling_period = c(-5, -5, -5, -4, -4, -4, -3, -3, -3, -2, -2, -2, -1, -1, 
                      -1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
                      6, 11, 11, 11, 22, 22, 22, 34, 34, 34, 46, 46, 46, 58, 
                      58, 58)
)


